# WordPress multiple Ajax Search URLs

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using typeahead to enhance the search on my woocommerce website. Therefore I'd like to split products and content results for different FE-Display.

Im using the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajax_search&fn=get_ajax_search&terms=[searchterm] to receive the results. Im trying to add something like "&posttype=post" or "&posttype=product" or "&posttype=page" to get different results.

But it seems, as it has no effect on the results. I can't limit the searchresults posttypes on the input field as I need all of these 3 resulttypes (and maybe more). Is there any chance to get different ajax-search URLs limited to the posttype?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Refer This URL [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240138/ajax-live-search-for-post-title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240138/ajax-live-search-for-post-title). It will help you. In this  $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'post' ) ); you can use insted of post type= post ,you can use 'product' or 'page'

Comment: Thank you @BijalPatel  the link told me everythin I've needed! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Bijal Patel I found the solution:

I've added a new action "shop_search" and made up several different search queries which can be called using &pts=posttype 
so I can go for different searches like ?action=shop_search&pts=product&terms=test
in functions

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_shop_search', 'shop_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_shop_search', 'shop_search' );
```

and then just like

```
function shop_search() {
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['pts'] ) && 'product' == $_REQUEST['pts'] ) { //pts = post type search // looking for Posttype = product
    $product_query = new WP_Query( array(
        's' => $_REQUEST['terms'],
        'post_type' => 'product', // Posttype goes here
        //'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
    ) );

    $presults = array( );

    if ( $product_query->get_posts() ) {

        foreach ( $product_query->get_posts() as $the_post ) {

            Do STUFF 

            $presults[] = array(
                'lorem' => $ipsum,
                'foo' => $bar,
            );
        }

    } else {
        $presults[] = __( 'Sorry. No results match your search.', 'wp-typeahead' );
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo json_encode( $presults );
}
```

can be endless like...

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['pts'] ) && 'post' == $_REQUEST['pts'] ) { //pts = post type search // Posttype = post
    $product_query = new WP_Query( array(
        's' => $_REQUEST['terms'],
        'post_type' => 'post', // posttype goes here
        //'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
    ) );

   $results = array( );
// see above for what to do next
// And Close it all afterwards
    die(); }
```

For all the posttypes I have to query, this may not be the fastest solution. If you just have to seperate between 2 or 3 posttypes, this will be it, more or less.
Call the searchresults using: mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=shop_search&pts=product&terms=test

So if anyone has an idea how to speed things up, please tell me!
Thank you. And a special Thank you to Bijal - you made my weekend!